# Error attach pdf to invoce e-mail

Tags: magento2, invoice, pdf, attachment

I tried to send an invoice email from frontend with pdf attached, by extending InvoiceSender like this:

```
namespace Namespage\Module\Model\Plugin\Order;

use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

class InvoiceSender extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\InvoiceSender
{
  public function send(Invoice $invoice, $forceSyncMode = false)
  {
      $invoice->setSendEmail(true);

      if (!$this->globalConfig->getValue('sales_email/general/async_sending') || $forceSyncMode) {
          $order = $invoice->getOrder();

          $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

          //start attact pdf invoce
          $pdf = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice')->getPdf([$invoice]);
          $date = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime')->date('Y-m-d_H-i-s');
          $pdf->render();
          $message = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Mail\Message');
          $message->createAttachment(
              $pdf->render(),
              \Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
              \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
              \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
              'invoice-'.$invoice->getId().'.pdf'
          );
          //end attach pdf invoce

          $transport = [
              'order' => $order,
              'invoice' => $invoice,
              'comment' => $invoice->getCustomerNoteNotify() ? $invoice->getCustomerNote() : '',
              'billing' => $order->getBillingAddress(),
              'payment_html' => $this->getPaymentHtml($order),
              'store' => $order->getStore(),
              'formattedShippingAddress' => $this->getFormattedShippingAddress($order),
              'formattedBillingAddress' => $this->getFormattedBillingAddress($order)
          ];
          $transportObject = new DataObject($transport);

          /**
           * Event argument `transport` is @deprecated. Use `transportObject` instead.
           */
          $this->eventManager->dispatch(
              'email_invoice_set_template_vars_before',
              ['sender' => $this, 'transport' => $transportObject->getData(), 'transportObject' => $transportObject]
          );

          $this->templateContainer->setTemplateVars($transportObject->getData());

          if ($this->checkAndSend($order)) {
              $invoice->setEmailSent(true);
              $this->invoiceResource->saveAttribute($invoice, ['send_email', 'email_sent']);
              return true;
          }
          return true;
      } else {
          $invoice->setEmailSent(null);
          $this->invoiceResource->saveAttribute($invoice, 'email_sent');
      }

      $this->invoiceResource->saveAttribute($invoice, 'send_email');

      return false;
  }

  protected function checkAndSend(Order $order)
  {
      $this->identityContainer->setStore($order->getStore());
      $this->prepareTemplate($order);

      /** @var SenderBuilder $sender */
      $sender = $this->getSender();

      try {
          $sender->send();
          $sender->sendCopyTo();
      } catch (\Exception $e) {
          $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
      }

      return true;
  }
}
```

the problem seems occure when `getPdf(...)` function being called, and shows an error like this:

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template
>   file: 'Magento_OfflinePayments::info/pdf/checkmo.phtml' in module:
>   'Magento_OfflinePayments' block's name: 'info\checkmo_0'
>
> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid
>   template file: 'Magento_OfflinePayments::info/pdf/checkmo.phtml' in
>   module: 'Magento_OfflinePayments' block's name: 'info\checkmo_0'

Answer (score 1):

Magento_OfflinePayments::info/pdf/checkmo.phtml file cannot be found.

This is due to a Core bug in 2.1, 2.2, maybe 2.3. Create a plugin to fix it :

- In app\code\Namespace\Module\etc\di.xml

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" ?>
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
      <type name="Magento\OfflinePayments\Block\Info\Checkmo">
          <plugin name="namespaceModuleCheckmo" 
              type="Namespace\Module\Plugin\Block\Info\CheckmoPlugin"
              sortOrder="1" 
          />
      </type>
  </config>
  ```
- In app\code\Namespace\Module\Plugin\Block\Info\CheckmoPlugin.php

  ```
  <?php

  namespace Namespace\Module\Plugin\Block\Info;

  /**
   * Class CheckmoPlugin
   * @package Namespace\Module\Plugin\Block\Info
   */
  class CheckmoPlugin {
      /**
       * @param \Magento\OfflinePayments\Block\Info\Checkmo $subject
       * @param callable $proceed
       * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
       */
      public function aroundToPdf(\Magento\OfflinePayments\Block\Info\Checkmo $subject, callable $proceed) {
          return __('Check / Money order');
      }
  }
  ```
- Finally, in command line :

  ```
  php bin/magento setup:di:compile
  php bin/magento setup:upgrade
  ```